# Undefined behaviour in C program. Please explain

Tags: c

Below is a program to add two numbers using bitwise operators. Though the final value returned in function add is as expected the value printed in main function is showing some junk value.Can anyone explain this undefined behaviour and let me know what is going wrong here.Sample output below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
int add (int, int);
int main ()
{
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    printf("\nSum: %d\n",add(n1, n2));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int add (int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    if (!a) {
        return b;
    } else {
        add ((a & b) << 1, a ^ b);
    }
}
```

Sample output:-

```
3 1
3 1
2 2
4 0
0 4
Sum: 2686756
```

Comment: You really ought to turn up the warning level on your compiler so it will actually tell you about this kind of simple error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `add ((a & b)`... is missing `return`, so it's just returning a random number off the stack.

Answer (score 6):

you need to return the result of add in your recursive call

```
int add (int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    if (!a) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return add ((a & b) << 1, a ^ b);
    }
}
```

which could be

```
  int add (int a, int b)
    {
        if (!a) return b;
        return add ((a & b) << 1, a ^ b);
    }
```

Comment: Or `return !a ? b : add ((a & b) << 1, a ^ b);` for us lazy people

Comment: Well let me 2 minutes then, creating C project to test :) I will edit my answer

Comment: @EdHeal  yes, it could!

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong (C is loooong time away) but

```
 if (!a) {
```

Is not bit "not" operator.

It will be "true" for every value, except 0

Edit :

See other answers. But in c++ ot's working :)

Comment: That's exactly as intended. If `!a`, then `a+b` is just `b`.

Comment: it can by the way a particular compiler works.  It should still be spitting out a warning

Comment: Naaan, must be visual taking care for me for this kind of errors (return). Not even a warning lol

Comment: Turn up your warning level. I'm using VS2013 and get "warning C4715: 'add' : not all control paths return a value". The code is malformed and only "works" by accident.

Comment: Thanks you. Will do. I actually never code (or almost never) in C/C++, so I’m on default settings