# Stack smashing detected. Can someone explain why?

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is my gcc version:

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

I have a simple C program which concatenates source string to target.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Strcat(char *t, char *s){  
    while(*t++);
    t--;
    while(*t++=*s++);
}

void main(void){
    char target[8] = "stack";
    char *source = "overflow";
    printf("%s\n", target);
    Strcat(target,source);
    printf("%s\n", target);
}
```

The above program give me this output with error:

```
$ a.out 
stack
stackoverflow
*** stack smashing detected ***: a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But when I initialise target array with size 9 instead of 8, like below, this program produces correct output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Strcat(char *t, char *s){  
    while(*t++);
    t--;
    while(*t++=*s++);
}

void main(void){
    char target[9] = "stack";
    char *source = "overflow";
    printf("%s\n", target);
    Strcat(target,source);
    printf("%s\n", target);
}
```

**Can somebody shed some light on why the first variant produces stack smashing error?**

Comment: `target` is just too small for "stackoverflow" string: undefined behaviour, that is in both cases...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behaviour in C program. Please explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123553/undefined-behaviour-in-c-program-please-explain)

Comment: Why did you pick 8,9?  What is wrong with 128?

Comment: Disabling security features **never** solves a problem. It only hides them so they can smash you later much harder. Btw. both variants invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user6365735 it's undefined behaviour. Why it works sometimes is beyond us.

Comment: The solution here is NOT a solution and should never be used.

Comment: @Olaf You don't answer my question. I know its an undefined behaviour. What I was asking is a reasonable answer to my specific question.

Comment: @user6365735 it's not beyond me. the detection is not done with an accuracy of 1 byte. So there's an implicit alert value somewhere. You seem to have found it. But the real solution is to increase your memory for the array so it's guaranteed to never happen. I'm not the only one who says so.

Comment: @user6365735: UB is the **only** answer to your question. You just did not show enough information. We are not a hindsight forum just to speculate what happens on your specific box, your specific environment, that day. If you want to learn more, use your debugger as it is intended to be used. Single step, read the machine code, etc. Anyway, it does not make sense to dig deeper, your code is just broken by design and no one should write such code. That's all to be said.

Comment: There is a lot to be learned by investigating the exact behaviour of what you describe but, unfortunately, you don't seem to understand that only you can do it, (and the answer may be different in a different moon phase).

Comment: @Olaf Which part is broken by design is this simple program except me trying to understand a phenomena?

Comment: PeterJ_01's answer is the exact reasoning I was searching for. @MartinJames. So yes I understood something from his answer which I don't understand from you calling it **UB** and not telling me how.

Comment: Obviously the stack smashing can only be detected if you have the compiler emit code to detect it. Turning off the generation of that code doesn't stop the stack from getting smashed; it just prevents you from hearing about it. Sort of like putting black tape over the "check engine" light on your car.

Comment: @user6365735: PeterJ_01's answer does not answer what is going on in **your** machine - unless he has direct access. It just explains what happens when he tried it once, not even if that will happen next time.  The rest is pure speculation. Learn about undefined behaviour and try to understand what it means. This is vital when programming C (and C++).

Comment: @Olaf You mean to say that this kind of behaviour is stochastic and not deterministic?

Comment: @user6365735: A digital computer should never behave non-deterministic. That'Äs the reason you cannot get true random value without external influence). It was written multiple times and I will reppeat it only once more: Learn about undefined behaviour! Maybe you know **about** it, but you don't know what it _implies_.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: ANother cause of UB: `void main(void)` -> `int main(void)`

Comment: @Olaf Why is `void main(void)` wrong or undefined behaviour?

Comment: and `char *source = "overflow";` not a true and accurate way to define a string. you must first allocate memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both programs are UBs but in the second case the stack guards were placed after the next stack alignment. It is usually 8 bytes. So you did not overwrite the guards and you did not get the error.

## but you still write outside the bounds.

Answer (score 4):

In **both** the cases, your *target* is too small to hold the concatenated result. Thus, inside the `Strcat()` function, you're accessing out of bound memory, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once you hit UB, there's no explaining the *reason*, because, there's no defined way to explain the outcome.

So, before you pass a target to store the concatenated result, **you** need to make sure that the target has enough memory to store the concatenated result, plus the null-terminator.

Comment: This does not give me the answer. I know that target is too small. But what is causing one program to print correctly and other one to give an error?

Comment: @user6365735 The answer is the part you somehow ignored, the link to the description of undefined behavior, in the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The both programs have undefined behavior because the memory beyond the array `target` is overwritten and the error message says about this.

The reason that the second program gives the expected result can be explained the following way.

The variable `source` having type `char *` is placed in memory properly aligned for pointers after the variable `target`. So as the variable `taget` is declared like

```
char target[9] = "stack";
           ^^^
```

the compiler could append the memory with additional bytes to provide the required alignment for the following variable

```
char *source = "overflow";
```

and these additional bytes could be used by the function `Strcat`.